Customizing vim-latex and Zathura preview setup for vertical split Screen
I have been using the vim-latex plugin alongside Zathura for editing LaTeX documents on my MacBook, and I am thoroughly enjoying the vim-latex-live-preview plugin.
As part of my workflow, I typically partition my screen into two vertical panes—one dedicated to editing my LaTeX file in Vim, and the other displaying the PDF preview in Zathura.
I would like to customize my setup so that when I execute the :LLPStartPreview command (or a custom command I define) in vim, the screen automatically splits into two vertical partitions: the left pane will display the Vim editor, and the right pane will show the zathura PDF preview generated by :LLPStartPreview.
I would greatly appreciate any assistance or suggestions on how to achieve this.

Welcome to TeX.SE!
